# Symfony Assert\Expression compare entity property with today's date

Tags: symfony, expression, entity, assert

I'd like to add an Assert\Expression to a property of my entity.
There should be an error message popping up, when the selected "Effective date" (this.getEffective()) is in the past or today. I just can't figure out, how to compare that date with todays date.

```
    /**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getEffective() > today",
 *     message="The effective date must be in the future!")
 */
private $status_stealth;
```

I tried the same with **now** or **datetime.now()** and I've google around a lot, but I haven't found anything where somebody actually compared another value with the current date within an Assert Expression.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new method in your entity which will return today's date time and in your expression do your comparison

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Expression(
 *     "this.getEffective() > this.getCurrentDate()",
 *     message="The effective date must be in the future!")
 */
private $status_stealth;

public function getCurrentDate(){
    return new \DateTime();
}
```

Comment: Using of `DateTimeImmutable` is better.

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, can I also check on whether status_stealth is actually checked?
so saying: "this.getStatusStealth() == true and this.getEffective() > this.getCurrentDate()"
it's not working yet, but I don't see why it wouldnt

Comment: @sonja you need to check expression syntax [expression language/syntax](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html) may be this should work `this.getStatusStealth() && this.getEffective() > this.getCurrentDate()`

Comment: @sonja I mean use `DateTimeImmutable` instead of `DateTime`. In this case, it's more correct. Also I added the answer, read it.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid unfortunately it's not working.. :/ still don't know why though. checked the syntax!

Comment: @sonja how about you do all the comparison in separate function and return true false, then in expression just put your function so if it returns  false valdtion error should appear

Answer (score 2):

By default, the expression syntax supports only one function, `constant()`. In turn, the expression validator comes with one or two variables (a validation value and a context object). You can pass a value to a validation method of the entity.

```php
/**
 * @Assert\Expression(expression="this.isStatusValid(value)")
 */
private $status;

public function isStatusValid($status) {
    $currentDate = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    return in_array($status, [1, 2, 3]) && $this->targetDate > $currentDate;
}
```

If you get some errors, just debug.

```php
public function isStatusValid($status) {
    $currentDate = new \DateTimeImmutable();
    var_dump($this->targetDate);
    var_dump($currentDate);
    die();
    return in_array($status, [1, 2, 3]) && $this->targetDate > $currentDate;
}
```

Documentation links: [Expression Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Expression.html), [Expression Syntax](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language/syntax.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can use the symfony's expression:

```
  $builder->add(
            'start',
            DateTimeType::class,
            [
                'label' => 'Campaign Starts At',
                'data' => $entity->getStart(),
                'required' => true,
                'disabled' => $disabled,
                'widget'  => 'single_text',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Assert\GreaterThan(['value' => 'today'])
                ]
            ]
        );
```